Label not included inside my tensor dataset
I am new at Machine Learning and I want to use pretrained model from BERT model.
I am facing the following problem: The label output is not inserted at the tensor type dataset.
Does anyone have a solution?
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X = feature['clean_text']
y = feature['label']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test= train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 42)
X_train = tokenizer(X_train.tolist(), padding = True, truncation = True)
X_test = tokenizer(X_test.tolist(), padding = True, truncation = True)
X_train = dict(X_train)
X_test = dict(X_test)
y_train = y_train.tolist()
y_test = y_test.tolist()
df_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train))
df_test = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_test, y_test))
inp, out = next(iter(df_train))
print(out)

Heres the Output: tf.Tensor(0, shape=(), dtype=int32)
